# How do I change the color functions available in base R to something that is color blind friendly?

Tags: r

I've tried multiple color packages, but the code is only accepting base R functions (rainbow, topo.colors, etc.). I need a color palette that works for people who are color blind. Sample data is not needed for this.

```
colors.use = topo.colors(nlevels(fish$Region))

for (i in 1:nlevels(fish$Region)) {
  predictions = predict(g1, type="response", newdata = data.frame(Distance= 1000, Average_Depth = seq(0,3000,length=1000), Region = levels(fish$Region)[i]))
  if (i == 1) plot(xlab= "Depth (m)", ylab = "fish/1000 m",seq(0,3000,length=1000), predictions, type = 'l', col=colors.use[i], pch=i)
if (i > 1) lines(seq(0,3000,length=1000), predictions,col=colors.use[i],pch=i)
}
```

Comment: Unless you've done something truly awful to the `lines` function, you can provide whatever colors you like in the colors.use vector and they'll work just fine. E.g. `colors.use = viridis::viridis(nlevels(fish$Region))`

Comment: You may not think you need sample data, but without it, we don't know how many colours you need. If it's only 2 to 4, then black, white and two shades of gray will do. If it's 1000, you're not going to be able to do it. Can you give us some guidance on what you need?

Comment: Further: it's **very important** to make use of line types and even line markers to distinguish multiple plots.   I urge you (and everyone :-) ) to read Ed. Tufte's books on graphics and data displays.

Answer (score 3):

The Okabe-Ito palette is available in base R, at least as far back as 2019 (according to `colorblindr` the original source is 'the article "Color Universal Design" by Okabe and Ito' ([here it is on the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210108233739/http://jfly.iam.u-tokyo.ac.jp/color/))

This example is straight from `example("palette")`:

```r
sinplot <- function(main=NULL) {
         x <- outer(
             seq(-pi, pi, length.out = 50),
             seq(0, pi, length.out = 8),
             function(x, y) sin(x - y)
         )
         matplot(x, type = "l", lwd = 4, lty = 1, col = 1:8, ylab = "", main=main)
     }
palette("Okabe-Ito"); sinplot("Okabe-Ito")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try package {[colorblindr](https://github.com/clauswilke/colorblindr)} or pick an appropriate palette (check option "colorblind-safe" from: https://colorbrewer2.org/.

Comment: Note that `colorblindr` is not available on CRAN - you need to follow the instructions at the link to install it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us how many colors you need, but color-blind safe palettes are normally limited to a maximum of 8 colors. If you can only use base R without add-on packages, you could just make a little palette function from hex codes widely available on the internet. For example, the [Wong](https://doi.org/10.1038/nmeth.1618) palette would be:

```
wong_pal <- function(n) {
  if(n > 8) stop("Select a maximum of 8 colors")
  c("#000000", "#e69f00", "#56b4e9", "#009e73", 
   "#f0e442", "#0072b2", "#d55e00", "#cc79a7")[seq(n)]
}
```

For example

```r
# Make example reproducible
set.seed(1)

cols <- wong_pal(8)

df <- as.data.frame(replicate(8, cumsum(rnorm(100))))

plot(1:100, seq(min(df), max(df), len = 100), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")

for(i in 1:8) lines(1:100, df[[i]], col = cols[i], lwd = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: can you add a link to where the Wong palette values come from ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker good idea - thanks. Wong now linked to doi

Answer (score 1):

The *viridis* palette is already built into base R!

According to [this](https://gabors-data-analysis.com/posts/2020/10/viridis/), it might indeed be suitable to compensate for color blindness.

In `?hcl.pals` it says:

> *"Green-Brown" or "Blue-Red 3" are colorblind-safe diverging palettes.*

Usually we can use the `hcl.colors` function,

```
hcl.colors(n, palette="viridis", alpha=NULL, rev=FALSE, fixup=TRUE)
```

it has *viridis* as default, but we can easily use the other palettes as well.

[image]

```
set.seed(42)
m <- replicate(8, rnorm(n=10)) |> apply(2, sort)

par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
matplot(m, type='l', lty=1, lwd=2, col=hcl.colors(n=ncol(m)), main='Viridis (built-in)')
matplot(m, type='l', lty=1, lwd=2, col=viridis::viridis(ncol(m)), main='viridis::viridis')  ## same
matplot(m, type='l', lty=1, lwd=2, col=hcl.colors(n=ncol(m), palette='Green-Brown'), main='Green-Brown')
matplot(m, type='l', lty=1, lwd=2, col=hcl.colors(n=ncol(m), palette='Blue-Red 3'), main='Blue-Red 3')
```